# Get Relation of Followed or Public User

Tags: mysql

I am working on a social app.  I have users that can have private accounts.  Users can also follow each other.  What is the fastest way using ActiveRecord or pure SQL to fetch all the records of a has_many on a User that either belong to someone I am following or belong to a public user.  In pseudo code:

User.get_all_posts_for_users_being_followed_by(me) + User.get_all_posts_for_public_users

I have this:

```sql
SELECT `posts`.*
FROM   `posts`
WHERE  ( user_id IN (SELECT id
                 FROM   users
                 WHERE  visibility = 'all'
                 UNION
                 SELECT followable_id
                 FROM   follows
                 WHERE  followable_type = "User"
                    AND follower_type = "User"
                    AND follower_id = 4
                    AND follows.status = 1) )
```

But I was hoping there might be a faster way to handle that, or a way to do it with Rails query methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform your clear query with ActiveRecord, but I recommend to use this pure version for_now, because it's very easy to modificate it now. You need pay attention on this:

1. The query might be faster, if you add indexes

   ```
   add_index :users, :visibility, :name => 'visibility_ix'
   ```
2. Selecting all columns with the * wildcard will cause the query's meaning and behavior to change if the table's schema changes, and might cause the query to retrieve too much data.
3. IN() and NOT IN() subqueries are poorly optimized. MySQL executes the subquery as a dependent subquery for each row in the outer query. This is a frequent cause of serious performance problems in MySQL 5.5 and older versions. The query probably should be rewritten as a JOIN or a LEFT OUTER JOIN, respectively.

Comment: I wanted to write as a join but cannot wrap my head around it.  Would you be willing to edit your answer with a join version of this query?

Comment: Alternatively, create 2 queries. Fetch users ids with first query. With second query, fetch users. It would be great, if you create smth like performance test suite, so you can manage speed of your query.